# kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO cause volume step down

Tags: audiounit

I'm using AudioUnit to Play and Record,when i set `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO`, the sound is lower than RemoteIO, Why?  Who can tell me how to change this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's lower because the voice processing algorithm and audio filters need some dynamic range, or headroom to turn the volume up and down, or have frequency response peaks above the average level.  Thus this processing needs to start with the volume lower so there is room to go up.

The way to change it is to not use Audio Unit voice processing.

Answer (score 0):

The way we got around the low volume of `VoiceProcessingIO` is to use an additional Compressor Audio Unit and control the gain from there. If you do so, don't forget to disable the AGC property of `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO`.

Comment: Does the Compressor Audio Unit workaround normalize the output volume? We saw that volume varies a lot depending on the inputs/outputs used with VPIO. Specifically, internal mic + bluetooth headset for output caused volume to be really low, but that doesn't happen for other setups. Or is this workaround valid for iOS only?

Comment: An Audio Compressor is different from normalization but can get close to it. It works on Dynamic Ranges (Google it). The problem actually comes from the fact that VPIO does NOT have the same behavior on different iPad/iPhone models and also output devices! On older devices you get Auto Mute (instead of echo suppression!) and so on so forth.

Comment: thanks! Is kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO production ready for a current macOS app? In my tests, volume was really low and manual gain was not a workaround because voice was really distorted.

Comment: @Arshia, if you have code on how you do this, that would be great!

Comment: In particular, if you can remove the ducking from this slightly-altered WWDC demo project, it would be much appreciated! https://github.com/winstondu/Voice-Processing-Demo